# Rails 4.2.3 activemodel preventing save after adding new fields to table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I added two fields to an existing table called `brands` using a migration:

```
def change
  add_column :brands, :about_the_brand, :string, limit: 2000
  add_column :brands, :user_id, :integer
end
```

Migration runs fine. In the Rails console:

```
brand = Brand.first
brand.user_id = 2
brand.save
```

I get this:

```
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
(0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
TypeError: nil is not a symbol
```

I can't find any meaningful reference to this error anywhere. This is a very simple operation, there is really no reason for it to fail that I can see.

The error is being thrown from:

```
activemodel-4.2.3/lib/active_model/dirty.rb:181:in `attribute_was'
```

which is:

```
# Handle <tt>*_was</tt> for +method_missing+.
def attribute_was(attr) # :nodoc:
  attribute_changed?(attr) ? changed_attributes[attr] : __send__(attr)
end
```

Comment: Can you check if you have an id column in your brands table ? This message can appear when you try to create an activerecord model with a non-default primary key

Comment: Great catch. I do NOT have an id in this table. It is populated from an external source, and can never be inserted to. All I ever need to do is update it. But I obviously can't do that with AR without having declared a unique id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a default primary key on the table fixed it:

```
self.primary_key = 'brand_id'
```